# How do I find the loop passing through certain points which maximizes a one form integral?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, calculus-of-variations, stokes-theorem

Suppose I have some points in a plane, and I want to integrate a form over a loop passing through all those points, how would I choose out of such loops the one which extremizes the integral?

Practically speaking, I'm trying to think if I have an engine which can operate in a certain range of pressure and volume, how I would let its state variable develop such that I get the maximum work.  So, I guess answer would be a some sort of generalisation of the carnot cycle.

If the form is closed over the region then this simply doesn't matter. I'm looking for non trivial cases.

Comment: Tag "calculus of variations" in the question shows the way. If order of passing points is not defined, then one needs to enumerate all possible orders.

Comment: Right. One may have situation where the degree of a state ( graph theory sense) is greater than two. However I think those answers can be physically ruled out because I think the best run should not have any ' revisiting' if that makes sense @IvanKaznacheyeu.

Answer (score 3):

There may not be a solution to this. Given your $1$-form $\omega$, set $d\omega = f(x,y)\,dx\wedge dy$. If $f$ happens to be zero on your set of points and one of the sets $\{(x,y): f(x,y)>0\}$, $\{(x,y): f(x,y)<0\}$ is bounded then you can take the component of the boundary containing your set of points. Orient it appropriately to get the largest/smallest integral. However, if $f$ is nonzero at any of the points, you can easily see that you can perturb any closed curve passing through the points to make the integral larger/smaller.